# When playlists are created, is a second copy of the song made?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, playlists, zune, zune-software

I'm curious about how playlists work, whether they be on a PMP, like the Zune, or on a PC, such as Windows Media Player or the Zune Software...  When a playlist is created, is a copy of the song made? eg, the playlist has it's "own" copy of the songs in the playlist?  OR, does it just "bookmark" where each song in its list is, and play it from there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A playlist is like a database of the locations of the songs selected by you usually stored/saved on your computer like a text file so depending on the number of songs the size of a playlist file will just be a few kb.

So it merely access the songs location and plays it accordingly (*you are right in saying that its  like a bookmark*) It doesn't make a copy of your songs.

Answer (score 2):

Playlists just point to the songs. They don't actually contain them.

As an example, I just created a playlist containing all my songs and it did not double the size of my library or take up any more space on my hard drive.